# Printing text on same line in messages buffer

Tags: message

How can I use `message` such that I keep writing on the same line

```
(message "Some text")

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/bin/rainbow-delimiters")
(require 'rainbow-delimiters))

(message "on the same line")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only reliable way is to save the messages as you go, concatenating each new one with the older ones. Something like this:

```el
...
(setq accumulated-messages (message "first"))

... stuff ...
(setq accumulated-messages (message "%s %s" accumulated-messages "second"))

... stuff ...
(setq accumulated-messages (message "%s %s" accumulated-messages "third"))

...
```

The problem with the `current-message` answer is that you have no control over what happens with the `stuff`: if it happens to use the echo area for its output, `current-message` will pick that up, instead of what you output with the `message` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works in your case, but maybe you can try to use `(current-message)` that returns the string currently displayed in the echo area, or nil if none

```
(message "%s" "toto")

;; ...

(message "%s %s" (current-message) "titi")
```